# How can I plan an experiment to change magnetic field of a coil rapidly while keeping the magnitude of oscillations constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Note: I might be completely wrong in my calculations, the important question is the one in the title.$$$$
For an experiment, I want to have an alternating current a conducting coil, and have the frequency of the change in the current accelerate with time but the current remain the same. So I want to find a function that describes the current I need to supply in order to achieve that. By faraday's Law:
$$\epsilon =- \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$$
But I am a bit confused about what I need the current I supply to be. I control V so:
$$I_{tot}=\frac{V}{R}+I_{in}+I_{faraday}=I_{in}+\frac{\epsilon}{R}=(I_{in}-\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t})$$
Since it is a coil, we have approximately:
$$I_{tot}=I_{in}-\frac{BA}{R}$$
Where B is the magnitude of the field of a because the field lines are parallel to the surface $A$. $B$ is linear with respect to the total current so:
$$I_{tot}=I_{in}-\frac{\alpha A}{R}I_{tot}$$
And this is a solvable equation. Now I am not sure how to proceed to find a function of $I_{in}(t)$ that will result in a total current of the form: $$I_{tot}(t)=Asin(\omega t)\Longrightarrow B=Bsin(\omega t)$$

Comment: Can you explain how you've broken down the currents more? What is the difference between $V/R$, $I_{in}$, and $I_{faraday}$? In your title question, do you mean you want the magnitude of the current to be constant? In principle, this will be hard to achieve if your frequency ramp comes close to the resonant frequency of the coil.

Comment: I think that $V/R = I_{in}$, and to my understanding $I_{faraday}$ is the voltage induced by faraday's law (time derivative of flux) divided by the resistance. Originally I changed the voltage using the function $V=sin(\omega t)$, but Faraday's law lowered the current. Is it possible to achieve even with low currents? Also, what do you mean by the resonant frequency of the coil? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the setup you are describing. Are you driving current into a coil which you want to keep constant, or are you inducing current into a coil, and you want the induced current to remain constant? If the former, niels nielsen has provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to drive your coil with a *signal generator* which automatically maintains constant drive current with changes in load impedance, as would occur as the drive frequency changes. This is called a *constant-current* source and a search will turn up a variety of circuits which will accomplish this.

A constant-current supply contains a current sensor (in simplest form, a series resistor across which a voltage is measured) that generates a voltage signal proportional to the current flow. That voltage is then used as a *control signal* in a *feedback loop* inside the power supply to automatically increase or decrease the source voltage so as to maintain constant current.

The current can be adjusted at any time with a knob that adjusts the *setpoint* of the variable voltage supply at its *summing junction*.

Since an open circuit would require ~infinite voltage to maintain constant current, constant-current supplies have protection circuits inside them which limit how high the source voltage is allowed to go, and shut the supply down if the load resistance is too high.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how a constant current source works? Can I change the current it controls while it is operating?

Comment: will add this info to my answer- NN